# Extension field obtained from polynomial

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

So, I stumbled upon this phrase in a book about cryptography:
"Another equivalent means of defining $t(x)$ as a primitive polynomial is to say that its roots generate the group of nonzero elements of the associated extension field **obtained from the polynomial $t(x)$ of degree $l$**"
What does "obtained from the polynomial" mean?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The book seems to be An Introduction to Cryptography, Second Edition
by Richard A. Mollin, page 118.

Answer (score 1):

It probably means the splitting field of $t$.